# Tkinter Canvas, hiding 100 objects using "tag" vs iterating through the ids of 10 objects and setting their state to "hidden". Which is faster?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Using the canvas in python tkinter, I'm hiding multiple objects these are my two approaches, which is more efficent?

Method 1

```
#This method iterates through the existing objects and sets their state to hidden.
        for id in graphics_data:
            canvas.itemconfig(id, state="hidden")
```

**Vs**

Method 2

```
#This method finds all the objects with the tag "drawing" and hides them.

canvas.itemconfig("drawing", state="hidden")
```

or more simply.

If I have 100 objects with the tag "drawing," and 50 of them are already hidden, will using the method to hide all at once by their tag take less time compared to if all 100 were initially visible?

I just want to see if Method 2 iterates through all the objects and hides them one by one under the hood.

Comment: A rule of thumb is, that using commands that act on c-level is faster than using higher level python.

Comment: Why don't you time both methods using `perf_counter()` from the `time` library? I bet that for 100 objects, it's not going to make much of a difference but for >1000, I think that using the `tcl`'s tag system will be faster than you looping in python. Also converting `tkinter` commands into `tcl` commands (what `tkinter` does under the hood), isn't very efficient so that will slow down your for loop.